# Notify thread to stop - raise event in another thread and class - C#

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

Simplifying, I have WPF application that has two class: a main window class with GUI and a worker class, which operates on a file. In main window, when user clicks a button, the worker thread starts.

I would like to make a button in main window, which stops worker. However not killing a thread, but notifying it, that user has aborted a thread and allow it to close writer and save file.

I was looking on stackoverflow for a long, but all questions are not about my problem. I would like to point out that I'm not iterating through a loop etc, therefore I cannot use a flag. I would like to raise an event from my main window on a thread class. How can I do that?

Comment: What data type are you using as your worker thread.  Is it a background worker, async task, thread?  Most have a cancellation token but if you are using a raw thread, I recommend switching to a background worker, otherwise you will have to implement this sort of logic yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a [CancellationTokenSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in your main window class. Send the [CancellationToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.token%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the worker thread. Code the worker to observe the token. MSDN has reference the cancellation patterns, review it there.

Whenever cancellation is needed, initiate it from UI thread by calling 
[CancellationTokenSource.Cancel()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321955%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You don't have to loop, you can observe if process is cancelled by waiting on [WaitHanndle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.waithandle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the token: CancellationToken.WaitHandle.WaitOne()

[WaitOne](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58195swd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will wait indefinitely until Cancel is called.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how can I notify my thread, that other thread  has used `Cancel()` method without checking in loop?

Comment: Updated my answer, check. You can use the WaitHandle.

Comment: Note the thread can also call [`IsCancellationRequested`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.iscancellationrequested(v=vs.110).aspx), which is generally lighter (a `WaitHandle` doesn't have to be generated).  If you don't want to periodically check `IsCancellationRequested`, you can call [`Register`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321635(v=vs.110).aspx) which is also lighter weight than a `WaitHandle`.

Comment: Ok, Thank you. I'm doing `token.Register(() => obj.Cancel());` in my MainWindow and running it by `cts.Cancel();` . In my thread class in `Cancel()` method I'm closing writer. however after calling Cancel application comes back to writing and throws exception. Can I prevent it and terminate a job in `Cancel()`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `CancellationTokenSource` https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
Just call its method `Cancel()` on button click.